# how to use ghci online- *h e l p*; it just scrolls fast?

Tags: haskell, ghci

when I tried to save the current ghci session using :save command I got the error

```
Prelude> :save
unknown command ':save'
use :? for help.
Prelude>
```

then when i type :? I got a ton of output that zoomed past the screen; how to read it one page at a time? is there anything like Unix `less` command there in ghci?

Comment: One approach is to use a terminal emulator with its own scrolling feature. What platform are you running?

Comment: Can't you just use your terminal's scroll bar or your mouse wheel?

Comment: @sepp2k how to use mouse wheel on terminal? the terminal doesn't even show a mouse pointer.

Comment: btw: I don't think there is a `save` command in ghci - you are probably looking for `:edit` (will open you editor)

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Usually a good way to scroll on a typical linux terminal is using `Shift+PgUp` and `Shift+PgDown`, do those work?

Comment: anyways - you can see all [commands](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) here

Comment: @Carsten I wanted to save the commands I entered in the current ghci session to a file, but it seems ghci doesn't support it (poor me)

Comment: @Carsten Which terminal are you using? Are you saying your mouse cursor disappears when you move it over the terminal window? That seems highly unusual (and unhelpful). Usually you can just use the mouse wheel by moving it while the window is focussed.

Comment: @bheklilr the `Shift+PgUp` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mntk123 I don't believe GHCi has the ability to save a session.  You're probably wanting more IPython like functionality.  For that, all I can say is try out the IHaskell kernel for Jupyter.  Most languages don't ship with REPLs as feature rich as IPython (Python doesn't ship with it either!), and there just hasn't been much call for it for Haskell.  You can try the readline bindings for Haskell, though, I've been able to use it to get the history into a variable, so if you can get that working then you could write your own GHCi command to do it.

Comment: @bheklilr thanks, can you turn your comment into answer?

Comment: @mntk123 You can use `tee foo.txt | ghci` to save a session's commands to `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run GHCi from your shell and use shell redirection. This works for me on Windows:

```
echo :? | ghci > help.txt
more help.txt
```

I would expect this to also work on Unix, although I can't actually try it.

Comment: It works in bash. In zsh you need to wrap quotes around ":?" (because otherwise `?` is a special character).

Comment: @sepp2k I have no idea what zsh is, other than the fact that it exists. I only use Bash. ;-)